# Make HAVING count(*) percentage based - complicated query with percentage calculations

Tags: mysql, sql

This query suggests friendship based on how many words users have in common. in_common sets this threshold.

I was wondering if it was possible to make this query completely % based.

What I want to do is have user suggested to current user, if **30%** of their words match.

curent_user total words 100

in_common threshold 30

some_other_user total words 10

3 out of these match current_users list.

Since 3 is 30% of 10, this is a match for the current user.

**Possible?**

```
SELECT users.name_surname, users.avatar, t1.qty, GROUP_CONCAT(words_en.word) AS in_common, (users.id) AS friend_request_id
    FROM (
      SELECT c2.user_id, COUNT(*) AS qty
      FROM `connections` c1
      JOIN `connections` c2
        ON c1.user_id <> c2.user_id 
          AND c1.word_id = c2.word_id
      WHERE c1.user_id = :user_id
      GROUP BY c2.user_id
      HAVING count(*) >= :in_common) as t1
     JOIN users
       ON t1.user_id = users.id
     JOIN connections
       ON connections.user_id = t1.user_id
     JOIN words_en
       ON words_en.id = connections.word_id
     WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM connections 
                  WHERE connections.user_id = :user_id
                    AND connections.word_id = words_en.id)
     GROUP BY users.id, users.name_surname, users.avatar, t1.qty
     ORDER BY t1.qty DESC, users.name_surname ASC
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c79a6/9

Comment: What do you want to select on? current user in common, or suggested user in common? If current user has 100 words and suggested user has 10 words, they can never have 30 words (30% for current user) in common. If they have 3 words in common, for current user that is only 3%, but for the suggested user 30%.

Comment: @jerdiggity what on earth does "anytime you want a number's percent value, divide 1 by the number" mean? I want 2's percent value, so 1 / 2 = 0.5 so 0.5%? or 50%? 50% of what?

Comment: @oerkelens exactly, I want to make both of them proportional. Make asymetric relationship symetrical.

Comment: oerkelens wanted to say that your example doesn't make sense, so you should update your question to fix it and make it clear.

Comment: @Tomas It is hard to explain the concept.

Comment: @Tomas try to re-read, I updated some parts. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: According to what you wrote - *"This query suggests friendship based on how many **words** users have in common"* - in your example the users **don't** match. **They don't have 30 words in common!**

Comment: @Tomas If I had already gotten query that would work like my example, than I would not ask the question would I? Current query suggests friendship based on words in common, I want new query to be like my example. Is it too hard to grasp this concept?

Comment: Salivan, it is really hard to understand you when you say something and than just show an example that is a complete contradiction. Did you see the contradiction I pointed out in my previous comment? Can you fix it? Is it really hard to give a *consistent* description of what you want?

Comment: @Tomas I don't understand what you want from me. My query works in one way, I want it to work like example. There is no contradiction. Simply state of affairs atm (query), and what I want to get (example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest a different way to look at your problem?

You might look into a similarity metric, such as [Cosine Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) which will give you a much better measure of similarity between your users based on words. To understand it for your case, consider the following example. You have a vector of words `A = {house, car, burger, sun}` for a user `u1` and another vector `B = {flat, car, pizza, burger, cloud}` for user `u2`.

Given these individual vectors you first construct another that positions them together so you can map to each user whether he/she has that word in its vector or not. Like so:

```
| -- | house | car | burger | sun | flat | pizza | cloud |
----------------------------------------------------------
| A  |  1    |  1  |   1    |  1  |  0   |   0   |   0   |
----------------------------------------------------------
| B  |  0    |  1  |   1    |  0  |  1   |   1   |   1   |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now you have a vector for each user where each position corresponds to the value of each word to each user. Here it represents a simple count but you can improve it using different metrics based on word frequency if that applies to your case. Take a look at the most common one, called [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

Having these two vectors, you can compute the `cosine similarity` between them as follows:

[image]

Which basically is computing the sum of the product between each position of the vectors above, divided by their corresponding magnitude. In our example, that is 0.47, in a range that can vary between 0 and 1, the higher the most similar the two vectors are.

If you choose to go this way, you don't need to do this calculation in the database. You compute the similarity in your code and just save the result in the database. There are several libraries that can do that for you. In Python, take a look at the [numpy library](http://www.numpy.org/). In Java, look at [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) and/or [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/).

Comment: I accept your answer for originality, but it was easier to implement the other answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

OK, so the issue is "users in common" defined as asymmetric relation. To fix it, let's assume that in_common percentage threshold is checked against user with the least words.

Try this query ([fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1556b/25)), it gives you full list of users with at least 1 word in common, marking friendship suggestions:

```
SELECT user1_id, user2_id, user1_wc, user2_wc,
       count(*) AS common_wc, count(*) / least(user1_wc, user2_wc) AS common_wc_pct,
       CASE WHEN count(*) / least(user1_wc, user2_wc) > 0.7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS frienship_suggestion
FROM (
    SELECT u1.user_id AS user1_id, u2.user_id AS user2_id,
           u1.word_count AS user1_wc, u2.word_count AS user2_wc,
           c1.word_id AS word1_id, c2.word_id AS word2_id
      FROM connections c1
      JOIN connections c2 ON (c1.user_id < c2.user_id AND c1.word_id = c2.word_id)
      JOIN (SELECT user_id, count(*) AS word_count
            FROM connections
            GROUP BY user_id) u1 ON (c1.user_id = u1.user_id)
      JOIN (SELECT user_id, count(*) AS word_count
            FROM connections
            GROUP BY user_id) u2 ON (c2.user_id = u2.user_id)
) AS shared_words
GROUP BY user1_id, user2_id, user1_wc, user2_wc;
```

Friendship_suggestion is on SELECT for clarity, you probably need to filter by it, so yu may just move it to HAVING clause.

Answer (score 2):

I throw this option into your querying consideration...  The first part of the from query is to do nothing but get the one user you are considering as the basis to find all others having common words.  The where clause is for that one user  (alias result OnePerson).

Then, add to the from clause (WITHOUT A JOIN) since the OnePerson record will always be a single record, we want it's total word count available, but didn't actually see how your worked your 100 to 30 threashold if another person only had 10 words to match 3... I actually think its bloat and unnecessary as you'll see later in the where of PreQuery.

So, the next table is the connections table (aliased c2) and that is normal INNER JOIN to the words table for each of the "other" people being considered.

This c2 is then joined again to the connections table again alias OnesWords based on the common word Id -- AND -- the OnesWords user ID is that of the primary user_id being compared against.  This OnesWords alias is joined to the words table so IF THERE IS a match to the primary person, we can grab that "common word" as part of the group_concat().

So, now we grab the original single person's total words (still not SURE you need it), a count of ALL the words for the other person, and a count (via sum/case when) of all words that ARE IN COMMON with the original person grouped by the "other" user ID.  This gets them all and results as alias "PreQuery".

Now, from that, we can join that to the user's table to get the name and avatar along with respective counts and common words, but apply the WHERE clause based on the total per "other users" available words to the "in common" with the first person's words  (see... I didn't think you NEEDED the original query/count as basis of percentage consideration).

```
SELECT
      u.name_surname, 
      u.avatar, 
      PreQuery.*
   from
      ( SELECT
              c2.user_id, 
              One.TotalWords, 
              COUNT(*) as OtherUserWords,
              GROUP_CONCAT(words_en.word) AS InCommonWords,
              SUM( case when OnesWords.word_id IS NULL then 0 else 1 end ) as InCommonWithOne
           from
              ( SELECT c1.user_id, 
                       COUNT(*) AS TotalWords
                    from
                       `connections` c1
                    where
                       c1.user_id = :PrimaryPersonBasis ) OnePerson,
              `connections` c2
                 LEFT JOIN `connections` OnesWords
                    ON c2.word_id = OnesWords.word_id
                    AND OnesWords.user_id = OnePerson.User_ID
                    LEFT JOIN words_en
                       ON OnesWords.word_id = words_en.id
           where
              c2.user_id <> OnePerson.User_ID
           group by
              c2.user_id ) PreQuery
         JOIN users u
            ON PreQuery.user_id = u.id   
   where
      PreQuery.OtherUserWords * :nPercentToConsider >= PreQuery.InCommonWithOne
   order by
      PreQuery.InCommonWithOne DESC,
      u.name_surname
```

Here's a revised WITHOUT then need to prequery the total original words of the first person.

```
SELECT
      u.name_surname, 
      u.avatar, 
      PreQuery.*
   from
      ( SELECT
              c2.user_id, 
              COUNT(*) as OtherUserWords,
              GROUP_CONCAT(words_en.word) AS InCommonWords,
              SUM( case when OnesWords.word_id IS NULL then 0 else 1 end ) as InCommonWithOne
           from
              `connections` c2
                 LEFT JOIN `connections` OnesWords
                    ON c2.word_id = OnesWords.word_id
                    AND OnesWords.user_id = :PrimaryPersonBasis
                    LEFT JOIN words_en
                       ON OnesWords.word_id = words_en.id
           where
              c2.user_id <> :PrimaryPersonBasis
           group by
              c2.user_id 
           having 
              COUNT(*) * :nPercentToConsider >= 
                SUM( case when OnesWords.word_id IS NULL then 0 else 1 end ) ) PreQuery
         JOIN users u
            ON PreQuery.user_id = u.id   
   order by
      PreQuery.InCommonWithOne DESC,
      u.name_surname
```

There might be some tweaking on the query, but your original query leads me to believe you can easily find simple things like alias or field name type-o instances.

Another options might be to prequery ALL users and how many respective words they have UP FRONT, then use the primary person's words to compare to anyone else explicitly ON those common words...  This might be more efficient as the multiple joins would be better on the smaller result set.  What if you have 10,000 users and user A has 30 words, and only 500 other users have one or more of those words in common... why compare against all 10,000... but if having up-front a simple summary of each user and how many should be an almost instant query basis.

```
SELECT
      u.name_surname, 
      u.avatar, 
      PreQuery.*
   from 
      ( SELECT
              OtherUser.User_ID,
              AllUsers.EachUserWords,
              COUNT(*) as CommonWordsCount,
              group_concat( words_en.word ) as InCommonWords
           from
              `connections` OneUser
                 JOIN words_en
                    ON OneUser.word_id = words_en.id
                 JOIN `connections` OtherUser
                    ON OneUser.word_id = OtherUser.word_id
                    AND OneUser.user_id <> OtherUser.user_id
                    JOIN ( SELECT
                                 c1.user_id, 
                                 COUNT(*) as EachUserWords
                              from
                                 `connections` c1
                              group by
                                 c1.user_id ) AllUsers
                      ON OtherUser.user_id = AllUsers.User_ID
           where
              OneUser.user_id = :nPrimaryUserToConsider
           group by
              OtherUser.User_id,
              AllUsers.EachUserWords ) as PreQuery
      JOIN users u
         ON PreQuery.uer_id = u.id
   where
      PreQuery.EachUserWords * :nPercentToConsider >= PreQuery.CommonWordCount
   order by
      PreQuery.CommonWordCount DESC,
      u.name_surname
```